# any changes in program doesn't affect on database

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net

The problem is - while program is working I change, add and delete data in datagrid.
But when I restart my program - it loads from database all data without any changes.(only add data works).

Where can be problem?

```
 public partial class StudentsTable : Window
{
    public StudentsTable()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    CourseWorkFinal.University0DataSet university0DataSet;
    CourseWorkFinal.University0DataSetTableAdapters.StudentsTableAdapter university0DataSetStudentsTableAdapter;
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        university0DataSet = ((CourseWorkFinal.University0DataSet)(this.FindResource("university0DataSet")));
        university0DataSetStudentsTableAdapter = new CourseWorkFinal.University0DataSetTableAdapters.StudentsTableAdapter();
        university0DataSetStudentsTableAdapter.Fill(university0DataSet.Students);
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource studentsViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("studentsViewSource")));
        studentsViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        university0DataSet.Students.StudentsRowChanged += new University0DataSet.StudentsRowChangeEventHandler(Modify);
        university0DataSet.Students.StudentsRowDeleted +=
            new University0DataSet.StudentsRowChangeEventHandler(Modify);

    }
    void Modify(object sender, University0DataSet.StudentsRowChangeEvent e)
    {
        university0DataSetStudentsTableAdapter.Update(university0DataSet.Students);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddStudent x = new AddStudent();
        x.Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    //    university0DataSetStudentsTableAdapter.Update(university0DataSet.Students);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Any number of places.  Most likely, you're not running any commands back to your DB to update the database.  Post your code and we can probably help.

Comment: posting your code and elaborating would probably get a few of those negatives undone.

Comment: It has created Window_Loaded automatically - so update and delete commands too I think. But when I add data I use connectstring abd Sqlcommand manually.

Comment: So you're assuming that update and delete are being created automagically for you, thus you didn't write any code for them, but your manually implemented add works correctly? Hmmmm....

Comment: Yes. But I create new connection and then create new SqlCommand and then use `cmd.Parameter.Add(param)` where `param=new SqlParameter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you are not committing the changes or you are using some sort of instance database that is part of your project, and thus being overwritten with the original database each time you compile/run from Visual Studio.

Will need to give more details on how you have your database setup in order to give a better answer.

Comment: I copy database to my project. And add it too. But if it overwrites every time why add function works?

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually save the newly added data in your DataGridView back to the database; it doesn't do it automatically.

If you want to get something more automatic, you could try setting up a `BindingSource`.  Here's a tutorial on that

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx